# How to use an arbitrary string encoding?

Tags: delphi, encoding

I'm trying to get some code working against an API published by a Chinese company.  I have a spec and some sample code (in Java), enough to understand most of what's going on, but I ran across one thing I don't know how to do.

```
String ecodeform = "GBK";
String sm = new String(Hex.encodeHex("Insert message here".getBytes(ecodeform)));  //test message
```

It's creating a string from the char array result of the hex representation of the original string, encoded in GBK format (the standard Chinese character encoding, equivalent to ASCII for English text).  I can work out how to do most of that in Delphi, but I don't know how to encode a string to GBK, which is specifically required by this API.

In `SysUtils`, there's a `TEncoding` class that comes with a few built-in encodings, such as `UTF8`, `UTF16`, and "Default" (the system's default code page), but I don't know how to set up a TEncoding for an arbitrary encoding such as GBK.

Does anyone know how to set this up?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `TEncoding.GetEncoding()` method to get a `TEncoding` object for a specific codepage/charset, eg:

```
var
  Enc: TEncoding;
  Bytes: TBytes;
begin
  Enc := TEncoding.GetEncoding(936); // or TEncoding.GetEncoding('gb2312')
  try
    Bytes := Enc.GetBytes('Insert message here');
  finally
    Enc.Free;
  end;
  // encode Bytes to hex string as needed...
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

`TEncoding` has a [`GetEncoding`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TEncoding.GetEncoding) method for that. Give it the encoding name or number, and it will return a `TEncoding` instance.

For GBK, the number I think you want is 936. See [Microsoft's list of code pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756.aspx) for more.